# Running multiple commands in a shell executable via web page

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to send commands to the bash shell through a webpage and echo the results to the webpage. The **php echo '....'** command works great to output the results of terminal commands.

My C program acts like a terminal itself, in that it continuously prompts the user for input and spits out the corresponding data correlating to the input.

```
 :~$ sudo ./program
 program_prompt> command1
 process has started
 program_prompt> command2
 process ended
 The output is foo bar
 program_prompt> ^C
 :~$
 :~$
```

I want to enter inputs into my fake terminal and continue to be able to enter inputs. From what I have gathered, I can pipe in strings into a command and sort of do this.

```
 echo "command1" | sudo ./program
```

This is the closest I have gotten to entering commands into my fake terminal. The fake terminal immediately ends after executing this command. I never get a chance to enter command2 and see the output. Im pushed back into the real terminal **:~$**

```
 :~$ echo "command1" | sudo ./program
 program_prompt> command1
 process has started
 program_prompt> :~$
```

I dont know if this is the proper path to do this. If I can do something different in php, js, or jquery to also accomplish please post a method.

Comment: For communicating with a interactive terminal program Expect http://expect.sourceforge.net/ may be the way to go.

Comment: The expect commands work amazingly. Thanks!